# Is the derivative of Riemann integral $\int_0^xf$, if it exists, always equal to $f(x)$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, riemann-integration

Let $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a Riemann integrable function. Define a function $F:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ by
$$F(x)=\int_0^xf.$$
Suppose that $F$ is differentiable at $c\in(0,1)$. Then is it necessarily true that $F'(c)=f(c)$ ?
Note that it is true if $f$ is continuous at $c$.

Comment: for discontinuous $f$, the limit for $F'$ may not exist, but if it does, how can it be anything else?

Comment: Suppose $f$ is continuous, then $F'(x) = f(x)$ everywhere in $[0,1]$.  What happens if you change the value of $f$ at a single point $c$?

Comment: This is pretty much a statement of the [Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus).

Comment: @gt6989b Apparently it can. See the answer below.

Comment: You can actually relax the condition of continuity at $c$ a bit to get the same result, i.e. $F'(c)=f(c)$. $c$ needs to be a so called Lebesgue point of $f$ (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_point and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Generalizations)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just take any continuous function with its value changed at a single point. For example let $f:[0, 1] \to \mathbb R$ be any continuous function and define $\tilde{f}: [0, 1] \to \mathbb R$ by
$$ \tilde{f}(x) = \begin{cases}
f(x) + 1 & \text{if $x = 1/2$}, \\
f(x) & \text{if $x \neq 1/2$}.
\end{cases}$$
Then since $f$ and $\tilde{f}$ differ by only a single point, they have the same indefinite integral
$$F(x) = \int_0^x f(x) \, \text{d}x = \int_0^x \tilde{f}(x) \, \text{d}x.$$
However $F'(1/2) = f(1/2) \neq \tilde{f}(1/2)$.